# How would you calculate the torque of a lever when it is submerged in a medium like dirt?

Tags: forces, kinematics, pressure, rotational-kinematics

I'm a high school student who hasn't had the pleasure of taking physics yet, so forgive me if the answer is obvious. The problem I have involves an earth anchor :
https://static.gemplers.com/img/auger-style-earth-227706-lrg.jpg
drilled vertically into the earth. I am trying to figure out the equation that would give the highest amount of permissible force uniformly distributed on the exposed top part before the anchor would rotate. Just a force perpendicular to the vertical auger. What I mean by rotate is that it would pivot at a point halfway down the auger, like a lever with a fulcrum in the middle, and not unscrew itself from the earth. 
 Of course this would be easy if it were in air, but I'm lost at how to calculate it in dirt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just look up friction in screws.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I mean a force perpendicular to it at the top that would cause it to rotate like a lever with a fulcrum halfway down the auger. It would be just like a regular torque problem but with lots of drag because of dirt rather than air

Comment: @AaronStevens like the perpendicular force it would take a bolt to move out of aluminum? I don't understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_(simple_machine)

Comment: @AaronStevens I'm talking about applying a uniform force across the flat top part of the auger until it moves as a lever around the x axis, not a force along one side of the top part until it rotates out along the z axis.

Comment: Oh ok. That is more complicated. It would depend on how far into the ground it is, as well as the composition of the earth it is in.

Comment: @AaronStevens It would be 9 inches in the ground and in a non-rocky soil of density 1.52 g/cm^3

Comment: This would be a good question for engineering, as soil mechanics is a common part of many a civil engineers curriculum

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this depends on the response of the soil to loads, and is not something that seems easy to calculate directly.  Knowing only the mass of the soil is not useful.  You could imagine replacing the soil with water.  The density would be similar, but would would allow the item to move with even the tiniest of loads.

You could probably calculate the pressure on the soil in response to a load (conservatively, just use the cross-section of the central post, and assume it is trying to rotate around the tip).  Then if you could find some values for the yield strength of the soil, you might get in the ballpark.  But looking at [this paper](https://www.newcastle.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0015/22623/82_The-ultimate-pullout-capacity-of-anchors-in-frictional-soils.pdf) on anchors in soil, it seems like there would be a lot of variables to consider before trusting the numbers to represent reality.

Comment: What if I knew that the anchor was rated to resist 440 N of vertical Pullout force? Could I solve to find the horizontal force required to move it or it is strictly empirical?